# Closing process causes high cpu usage in input.readLine()

Tags: java, multithreading, input, process

I have code that runs cmd.exe process with **ProcessBuilder** and when I destroy this process with
`process.destroy();` the CPU usage incrases (0% > 30%). Every time I start and destroy cmd.exe new Threads appear that causes cpu usage up to 100%. Can I somehow stop this loop when the InputStream ends? It is also the same in my another app when Server stops with eg Ctrl-C and client have high cpu usage.

`input.readLine();` wants to read from not exisitng InputStream and causes high cpu usage. It is stuck at this line.

I use Java 8

**Code:**

```java
InputStream inputraw = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputraw));
while(true)    
{
    String cmd = input.readLine(); //HERE!
    //write cmd to console functions.....
}
```

```java
if (isWindows) {
    command = (String.format("cmd.exe"));
} else {
    command = (String.format("sh"));
}
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder()
    .command(command)
    .redirectErrorStream(true);
process = pb.start();
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `(String.format("cmd.exe"))` instead of just writing `"cmd.exe"`? Besides that, what kind of “new Threads appear”, if not threads you are actively creating?

Comment: This is only part of my code. The String.format("cmd.exe") was here before to run String.format("cmd.exe /c %s",cmd).

Comment: `String.format("cmd.exe /c %s",cmd)` still is an unnecessarily complicated and inefficient way to say `"cmd.exe /c %s" + cmd`. But anyway, the crucial point are the new threads you mentioned but didn't provide information about.

Comment: @Holger the threads aren't the issue i've fixed it temporarly by making input.readLine in thread and kill it after some timeout on my server app. The issue is code stuck at input.readline(). In debugger code is stuck here

Comment: It runs serval cmd.exe eg 5 and when i kill every cmd.exe CPU goes to 100%

Comment: Then, I suggest removing that misleading phrase "new Threads appear". I've seen this phenomenon before, `FileInputStream` going to a 100% CPU (on one core) when trying to read from a broken pipe. I'd avoid `BufferedReader.readLine()` and use `inputStream.read(byteArray, 0, (int)Math.min(inputStream.available(), byteArray.length()))` to avoid any blocking read and do the processing (conversion to string, splitting to lines) later. But when all you're doing with the output is writing it to the console, use `redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)` on the `ProcessBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've found some solution to this problem:

(If you want to post better answer you can still do it)

```java
    public static String readLine(InputStream s) throws Exception {
        String cmd = "";
        try {
            int ch = s.read();
            cmd += (char) ch;
            StringBuilder cmdBuilder = new StringBuilder(cmd);
            while (ch != 10 && ch >= 0) {
                ch = s.read();
                if (ch == 10 || ch < 0) break;
                cmdBuilder.append((char) ch);
            }
            cmd = cmdBuilder.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception("Input was empty!");
        }
        return cmd;
    }
```